# Vue: How to detect when all components have finished loading?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I want to show a loading icon while all components are still loading, and it will disappear when all components have finished loading data.

Is there any global way to know when everything has been loaded instead of manually checking components one-by-one?

Layout:

```
<template>
  <LoadingBar :loadingBar="loadingBar" />
  <NuxtLayout name="root">       
      <slot />       
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

Page: that uses the above layout

```
<template>
 <LazyComponent1 v-cloak /> => run its own data
 <LazyComponent2 v-cloak /> => run its own data
 <LazyComponent3 v-cloak /> => run its own data
</template>

<style lang="sass">
[v-cloak] 
  display: none
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your App component:

```js
export const eventBus = new Vue();
//...
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loadingCount: 0, // Number of components still loading
      loadingBar: false // Show/hide the loading bar
    };
  },
  created() {
    eventBus.$on('componentLoading', () => {
      this.loadingCount++;
      this.loadingBar = true;
    });

    eventBus.$on('componentLoaded', () => {
      this.loadingCount--;
      if (this.loadingCount === 0) {
        this.loadingBar = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

then from each child component you import `eventBus` then you do `eventBus.$emit('componentLoading')` before loading data and `eventBus.$emit('componentLoaded');` when data is loaded and based on `loadingBar` you show/hide your loading bar

Comment: thanks for the idea, I can use provide/inject in vue3 but sometimes I'm just lazy to repeat one thing :D